# Test computing a model's hasMany relationship in EmberJS

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

I'm trying to add a unit test for a computed property in a model where it lookup a property that is a hasMany relationship to retrieve one of them base on anothers property criteria.

Here is the main code:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

import {computed} from '@ember/object';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    gamePlayers: DS.hasMany('gamePlayer', { async: false }),
    sessionUserId: DS.attr('number'),

    heroPlayer: computed('sessionUserId', 'gamePlayers', function() {
        const userId = parseInt(this.get('sessionUserId'));
        const heroPlayer = this.get('gamePlayers').find(player => player.get('userId') === userId);
        return heroPlayer;
    })
});
```

And here is how I'm trying to test it:

```
import { moduleForModel, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import { run } from '@ember/runloop';

moduleForModel('game', 'Unit | Model | game', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  needs: ['model:gamePlayer']
});

test('heroPlayer retrieves the player where userId matches the session', function(assert) {
    const store = this.store();
    const done = assert.async();
    run(() => {
        const gamePlayers = [store.createRecord('gamePlayer', {userId: 111}), store.createRecord('gamePlayer', {userId: 222})];
        const sessionUserId = 111;
        const model = this.subject({ gamePlayers, sessionUserId });
        assert.equal(111, model);
        done(); 
    })
});
```

But does not matter how I implement the test I always get different issues where i cannot create `gamePlayer` objects inside the unit test.

In this case the ember test suite drops a bunch of backbunner errors like this one:

```
Expected:   
{
  "__OVERRIDE_OWNER__ember1517897244339342530367001__": {
    "__POST_INIT__ember15178972443391088345028564__": function(){
...
    at http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:762:20
    at Backburner._run (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:20474:35)
    at Backburner.run (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:20197:25)
```

What's the ember way to cover this kind of scenario? I'm using Ember 2.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the approach was correct but the code inside the run was incorrect, looks like i was trying to `assert.equal` the model instead of the `heroPlayer` property, this snnipet fixed the issue:

```
run(() => {
    const gamePlayers = [store.createRecord('gamePlayer', {userId: 111}), store.createRecord('game-player', {userId: 222})];
    const sessionUserId =  111;
    const model = this.subject({ gamePlayers, sessionUserId });
    assert.equal(111, model.get('heroPlayer.userId'));
    done();
});
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue for me. I get an error similar to:-
`Error: Cannot set read-only property 'gamePlayers' on object